# Can S-Corp loss offset gain?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, capital-gains-tax, s-corporation

I made 2 investments via my S-Corp. The first, in apartment buildings which is being sold for a gain, and the second in a hi-tech startup which failed and closed.
Can the loss from the startup offset the gain from the buildings?
Are there limitations? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the losses can offset the gains.

There is a limitation: S-Corp is disqualified if it has more than 25% of passive income. So unless you *earn* 3 times more than your income from these sales, you're going to end up with C-Corp and double taxation.

Investing via S-Corp is a very bad idea.

Comment: Thanks littleadv, if I had invested in the startup personally, not via S-corp, would the loss offset the S-corp gain from the property sale? BTW, the S-Corp had losses.

Comment: @NAInvestor it would. It doesn't matter if it had losses, what matters is the income, revenue. I.e.: if 25% or more of your income is from passive activity - you'll be taxed heavily on the corporate level, and if it happens more than twice - you lose your S-Corp status.